# Show field in template but dont allow it to be edited (Django)

Tags: django

Say I have a model

```py
class MyModel(model.Models):
    name = model.CharField()
    age = model.IntField()
```

Then in my template I want to display the `name` but only allow `age` to be changed i.e the user should not be able to modify what is written in the `name` field but it should just be there to show, which name they are editing the age for.

My template is as the following

```html
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="content-section">

  <div class="form-group">
    

    {{form.name|as_crispy_field}} <!--   Can still edit this field -->

    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form.age|as_crispy_field}}
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Update</button>
      <a role="button" class="btn btn-outline-info" href="{% url 'my_list' %}"> Wups, take me back!</a>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Why are you adding `name` to the model form? You can just leave it out and pass name to the template as a variable, then render it.

Comment: I like formatting of the fields, thus I tried to keep it, instead of writing the html/css my self for a box with the link in it etc.

Comment: have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827526/django-creating-a-form-field-thats-read-only-using-widgets

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Melvyn, you dont't need to pass `name` to the form. Just pass it as a variable to your template, then create a read only input field and customize it as you want:

`<input value="{{ name }}" readonly/>`

Comment: Yes, but it won't be actually used, because `name` is not on the form. There is no such thing as client-side safety, users can submit whatever they want.