# Overriding initial value in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

in my Django (1.2) project, I want to prepopulate a field in a modelform, but my new value is ignored.
This is the snippet:

```
class ArtefactForm(ModelForm):
    material = CharField(widget=AutoCompleteWidget('material', force_selection=False))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ArtefactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['material'].initial = 'Test'
```

I also tried with `self.base_fields`, but no effect: there is always the database-value displaying in the form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
    initial['material'] = 'Test'
    kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(ArtefactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 19):

<sup>Old question but adding a descriptive answer as I believe it would be helpful for some new developer.</sup>

> I also tried with `self`.`base_fields`, but no effect: there is always the database-value displaying in the form. Any ideas?

If a form is "initialized" form, either:-

1. using `initial` argument (eg. `YourModelFrom(initial={'filed1': variable})` — generally the case, when you want to pass dynamically calculated initial values for some fields). Reference [`Setting Initial Values`](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html)

   or
2. using `instance` argument (eg. `YourModelFrom(instance=model_object)` — usually the case, when you wants to update an existing model instance object) .  References read ModelFrom's [`save() method`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

   <sub>Note:

   1  [`ModelFrom`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L466) class inherits [`BaseModelFrom`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L305) class.  The [`BaseModelFrom`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L305) class inherits [`BaseForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L109) class.

   2 The argument `instance` is added in [`BaseModelFrom`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L305) class constructor, when we assign a model class instance object to `instance` argument (hence `instance is not None`) then [`BaseModelFrom`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L305) constructor calls `model_to_dict()` and updates `initial` argument before to call super class constructor. Check [`def __init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L306) in BaseModelFrom class</sub>

Then assigning initial value to a field explicitly (as shown in OP's code in question) don't effect, this is due to the way [`_clean_fields`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L384) method is written in `BaseFrom` class.

Code Snip:

```
def _clean_fields(self):
    for name, field in self.fields.items():
        value = field.widget.value_from_datadict(
                self.data, self.files, self.add_prefix(name))
        try:
            if isinstance(field, FileField):
                initial = self.initial.get(name, field.initial) # <- Check
                value = field.clean(value, initial)
            else:
```

According to code line `initial = self.initial.get(name, field.initial)`, if initial value for field is given in `initial` dict then value assigned to `field.initial`  is *not* used.

**[ANSWER]**:

Although, @Daniel answer is perfectly correct but one can also like another way to achieve same effect is using `self.initial`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArtefactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['material'] = 'Test'
```

Give it a try!!

`self.initial` is nothing but it the dict we pass in argument. Check code [`__init__`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L122) in `BaseForm`:

```
class BaseForm(object):
    def __init__(........
                 ........):
        :
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.initial = initial or {}  # <-- Notice 
        self.error_class = error_class
        :
```

Note: I didn't find any documentation related to use initial attribute, I just explored the base code and used it.

**Edit:** the behavior reported in Question is also documented in Django Model

> ### [Dynamic initial values](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)
>
> #### Form.initial
>
> Note that if a `Field` defines `initial` and *you* include `initial` when
>   instantiating the Form, then the latter `initial` will have precedence.
>   In this example, `initial` is provided both at the field level and at
>   **the form instance level, and the latter gets precedence:**
>
> ```
> >>> from django import forms
> >>> class CommentForm(forms.Form):
> ...     name = forms.CharField(initial='class')
> ...     url = forms.URLField()
> ...     comment = forms.CharField()
> >>> f = CommentForm(initial={'name': 'instance'}, auto_id=False)
> >>> print(f)
> <tr><th>Name:</th><td><input type="text" name="name" value="instance" />
> <tr><th>Url:</th><td><input type="url" name="url" /></td></tr>
> <tr><th>Comment:</th><td><input type="text" name="comment" /></td></tr>
> ```

<sub>PS: Btw, point 2 in my answers tell difference between `initial` and `instance` argument. Their is one more key-value argument `data` - values in that triggers form validations. read this [Difference between Django Form 'initial' and 'bound data'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7920128/1673391).</sub>

Comment: **Note:**  In bound form, `data` (the query dict) will have precedence over initialized field's value. Check code: [`def value(self)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L610) and method [`def bound_data(self, data, initial)`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/fields.py#L165) -- this will help you if you have a value for a field os dynamically calculated and the filed is ['disabled'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1424453/1673391). Let me know if anyone need help on this I will update this answer!

Comment: self.initial[field] did the trick here. Thank you very much.