# Django forms which fields are required as "bound" fields to validate

Tags: django, django-forms

Per this question: [Difference between Django Form 'initial' and 'bound data'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920128/difference-between-django-form-initial-and-bound-data) :

> Here's the key part from the django docs on bound and unbound forms.
>
> If it’s bound to a set of data, it’s capable of validating that data and rendering the form as HTML with the data displayed in the
>   HTML.
>
> If it’s unbound, it cannot do validation (because there’s no data to validate!), but it can still render the blank form as HTML.

My question is:
Is there an easy way to know *which* fields *need* to be bound in order to validate?

We have a multi-inheritance ModelForm nightmare and it's really tough to figure out which what are the minimum required fields to "bind".

In this case I've tried matching my `form.data` to  `vars(form.fields)`, but this is not enough, it's just ongoing potluck tracking back through the models and adding more and more to the `form.data` in an ad-hoc way.

Is there some cardinal list somewhere of the minimum requirements of bindable fields?

Comment: Your question is a bit odd; because there is no such thing as "bindable field". A bound form just means there is _some_ data added to it; the data may not be complete - that is, it may not represent all fields in the form; and thats perfectly fine. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks Burhan, there is _some_ data, but the form is still `form.is_bound=False`. What I want to know is what more I need to add to the data in order for `is_bound` to be True.

Comment: Can you post some code? It would be much easier to figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your clarifying comment:

> [T]here is some data, but the form is still form.is_bound=False. What I want to know is what more I need to add to the data in order for is_bound to be True.

It's not a question of what data is present or absent, it's a question of how you construct the form object.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form):

```
To create an unbound Form instance, simply instantiate the class:

>>> f = ContactForm()

To bind data to a form, pass the data as a dictionary as the first parameter to your Form class constructor:
>>> data = {'subject': 'hello',
...         'message': 'Hi there',
...         'sender': 'foo@example.com',
...         'cc_myself': True}
>>> f = ContactForm(data)
```

That is, if you provided an argument when instantiating the form, it's bound.  If not, not.

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I was adding data post-hoc and apparently this was what was making it seem as though the form was unbound.