# Django form errorlist appears even when there is no attempt to submit

Tags: django, django-forms

My page when requested through GET appears already with error "This field is required.", which is not a desirable behavior. I want this error appears when user actually attempts to submit a form without a data required.

This is my form Python class:

```
class Place_A_Bid_Form(forms.Form):
    listing = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"type":"hidden"}))
    bid = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":"form-control"}),
    min_value=1)
```

Form's html:

```
<form action="{% url 'place_a_bid' listing.title %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                        {{ form }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Place a bid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

And view:

```
def details(request, listing):
    listing_obj = Listing.objects.get(title=listing)
    form = Place_A_Bid_Form({"listing":listing_obj.title})
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    if listing_obj in user.created_listings.all():
        return render(request, "auctions/details.html", {
            "listing": listing_obj,
            "categories": categories,
            "creator": True
        })
    elif listing_obj in user.watchlist.all():
        return render(request, "auctions/details.html", {
            "listing": listing_obj,
            "categories": categories,
            "in_watchlist": True,
            "form": form
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "auctions/details.html", {
            "listing": listing_obj,
            "categories": categories,
            "in_watchlist": False,
            "form": form
            })
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean form gets submitted without clicking the submit button when page reloads ?

Comment: @Alex Stelmakh what errors show in the form?

Comment: @babak gholamirad "This field is required."

Comment: @Ahtisham no. Right away after rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in that your form has no method, so it defaults to GET. It should be

`<form action="{% url 'place_a_bid' listing.title %}" method="post">`

**Now why are you getting errors even if the form is not being submitted?**

This `form = Place_A_Bid_Form({"listing":listing_obj.title})` creates a bound form, which will give the error since `bid` is required and missing.

Perhaps what you intended is to create an unbound form with initial data, like this:

`form = Place_A_Bid_Form(initial={"listing":listing_obj.title})`

This will create the same looking form on your html, but since it's not bound, it will not give any errors, unless it is *submitted* with the missing `bid` field.

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/api/) on bound and unbound forms, and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920128/difference-between-django-form-initial-and-bound-data) about how to provide initial data to each.