# Django ModelForm: how do I stuff in an initial value after it is constructed

Tags: django-forms

The question of how to supply an initial value in a ModelForm is well answered:
[Overriding initial value in ModelForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988548/overriding-initial-value-in-modelform)

But how do I stuff a value in after the model is created?  Or how would I correct this code?

```
class Entry_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Entry
        exclude = ('')
```

:

```
def entry_add(request, pk):
    form = Entry_form
    selected_text = request.GET.get('selected_text', '')
    form.fields['title'].initial = 'Test: ' + selected_text
    return render(request, 'entry_add,{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors in your code.

1. Remove the line:

   `exclude = ('')`

   `('')` is an empty string, not an empty tuple.
2. `form = Entry_form` should be `form = Entry_form()`
3. `return render(request, 'entry_add,{'form': form})` - missing closing quote.

The line:

```
form.fields['title'].initial = 'Test: ' + selected_text
```

Is correct, and should work.

An alternative way is:

```
form.initial['title'] = 'Test: ' + selected_text
```