# How to display more things in admin.StackedInline

Tags: django, django-admin

I have Article model and a Comment model. Comment is created in admin.py as admin.StackedInline, and it has several fields, notably content and lastUpdate. For lastUpdate, i have specified as follows: lastUpdate = models.DateTimeField('last update', auto_now=True). Understandably, lastUpdate is not displayed when i try to add new comment (or edit old ones). However, i would like it to display for older comments if possible, as a read only thing. Is there anyway of accomplishing that?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess if this http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields doesn't do what you want it to do, have a look at this: [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-be)

Comment: As a side note, i didn't realize setting read_only flag on the field i wish to display will solve this problem. I tried list_display.

Comment: as a side note - admin.StackedInline ignores list_display