# How to use new Django 1.2 readonly_fields in ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to use the new readonly_fields in a ModelForm.

```
class TrainingAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TrainingTasks
        readonly_fields = ('trainee_signed','trainee_signed_date')
```

But this does not work. Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing it in a form, see [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-be)

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), this is a member of `admin.ModelAdmin`, not `forms.ModelForm`. Your admin form needs to inherit from `admin.ModelAdmin` in order for you to have access to the `readonly_fields` option.

**Edit**:
I mis-read the original question, I thought you were trying to use the field within Django's supplied admin app. However, as seen in my initial response, this option is only available for classes that inherit from `admin.ModelAdmin` — you will not be able to use it via `forms.ModelForm`.