# In Django, how can I make a field read only the first time a form is loaded?

Tags: django, forms, readonly

I have model form and I need to have one of the fields be read only until after it's saved. I haven't figured out a good way to do this, and below is what I have in my admin.py.

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    trac = forms.URLField(min_length=400, required=False)
    impacted_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    formfield_overrides = {
    }

    class Meta:
        model = Request

class RequestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = RequestForm
    list_display = ['id', 'title', 'priority', 'requestor', 'status']
    list_filter = ['requestor', 'priority', 'impacted_users']
    actions = [complete]

    class Media:
        js = (
            '/media/js/jquery.js',
            '/media/js/hide.js',
            )

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.requestor = request.user
        instance.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the field in question is `special_field`.

Here's how you'd do it (from [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-be/325038#325038)):

```
class RequestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    trac = forms.URLField(min_length=400, required=False)
    impacted_users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    formfield_overrides = {
    }

    def __init__(self, special_field_starting_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequestForm,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if not (instance and instance.id):
            self.fields['special_field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['special_field'].initial = special_field_starting_value

    class Meta:
        model = Request
```

This will work in both admin and in a normal view.

**Full disclosure**: actually, I haven't tested it, but assuming the answer I linked to is still valid, then the code I wrote based on this should also be valid.

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be done in the controller (called View in Django).

In the view handling your form, check for a line like that :

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
else:
    ...
```

This should look like the view of the [official documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). (There should also be a test to check if `form.is_valid()` in the first part of this `if`.)

The first part of this logical bloc is executed whenever it is not the first time the user loads the form (ie. invalid entries). The second part, the `else`, is what happens when the form is loaded for the first time.

You can check to manipulate the form widget in the according section of this logical bloc.
Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-be) to set an input field read only. You should be able to modify your form class at this point.

Comment: I haven't implemented any views yet, I was hoping I could do this in the admin, since it will be mainly administrators looking at this. Looks like it's time to leave the admin behind :)