# How to render CharField into static text in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I started to code in Django quite recently, so maybe my question is a bit wierd.
Recently I needed to render the `CharField` fields from the model into simple static text in html , but I figured out that it seems it's not that simple in this case as I could think, or I am doing something wrong...

I have this model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    CATEGORIES = (
        (0, 'category0'),
        (1, 'category1'), 
        (2, 'category2'), 
        (3, 'category3'), 
        (4, 'category4'), 
        (5, 'category5'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    category = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Form class for it is:

```
class TagForm(ModelForm):
    category = ChoiceField(choices=Tag.CATEGORIES)

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
```

in views I create the formset with multiple `Tag` objects in a single form with providing `TagForm` class for each `Tag` object in it:

```
TagsFormSet = modelformset_factory(Tag,exclude=('user'),form=TagForm,extra=0)
form = TagsFormSet(queryset=all_tags)
```

and in the template I have:

```
{{ form.management_form }}   
{% for tagform in form.forms %}
{{ tagform }} 
<hr>
{% endfor %}
```

But this way in the html, "name" and "description" fields of the model are always rendered as input text field. I would like to have them in the html just as normal static text without anything (in that html at the moment I only need to display them). Is there any quick solutions for this case?

Answer (score 4):

In your form's meta class, add the following to remove the fields

```
exclude = ('name', 'description'),
```

then display the values in your template with

```
{{ tagform.instance.name }}
{{ tagform.instance.description }}
```

Also, the choices argument should be passed to the category model field; that way you won't need to explicitly define the field in the form.

Answer (score 0):

It might be sufficient to render the field as readonly (so the browser refuses to modify the data), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-be).

Comment: Hi Martin,thanks for answer.  Yes this solution I tried before, but in fact this way edit box is disabled but still visible around text. My aim is to completely remove this edit box and leave there just plain text instead of it, but this one I don't know how to achieve...

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely want to render just the text, you need to define a custom widget, then map the form field to this widget. In the widget's render() method, output just the field value.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want input fields, why do you use Django's forms?

You can also just give an object list to the template and render the object fields any way you like.