# How to persist JSF view parameters through validation

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using JSF 2.0/CDI and PrimeFaces 2.2.1 for a number of CRUD forms that let the user view or update the attributes of an existing entity by clicking on a link in a datatable, where the identifier of the entity is passed to the CRUD form as a View Parameter.  I display the entity's ID (often just an integer) on the CRUD form in a PrimeFaces InputText field with the readonly attribute set to true (since I can't let them change it), so the user knows which entity they're editing.  The backing bean of the CRUD form is RequestScoped, which works fine except when validation fails.  In that case, the value of the View Parameter is lost, so a 0 is displayed in the entity ID field on validation failure.

I am able to maintain the actual entity ID in a hidden field so it's available to update the database once validation succeeds, but it's rather maddening that I've not been able to find a way to maintain the value in a visible field of some sort after a validation failure.  Ideally the InputText field would retain its functionality as an inputted and validated field even with its readonly (or disabled) attribute set to true, which would let me forgo the hidden field entirely.  But it doesn't appear that I can make it work that way.  Any suggestions besides making the backing bean ConversationScoped, which I'd prefer to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, after stating what I'm looking for a little differently in a Google search I found a novel suggestion at the link below that seems to work cleanly.  Instead of making the entity ID field readonly or disabled, I leave it enabled but blur it as soon as it receives focus.  I'm able to get rid of the hidden field, the user can't change the value and it survives a validation failure.

```
<p:inputText id="entid" value="#{RequestBean.entityID}" onfocus="blur();" />
```

http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-1738.html