# convert form field to label or text in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form field (dropdown) that I don't want users to edit, but only see its value as a label or text.

It simply looks like this:

{{ form.activity }}

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: It should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313446/readonly-fields-in-django-formset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a readonly attribute in the widget attrs.

Comment: how do you do that on a modelformset where there is no form?