# How to make ChoiceField readonly in django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    CHOICES = (('1', 'one',), ('2', 'two',))
    one_or_two = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, initial='1') 

def show(request):   
    form = MyForm()   
    # render form
```

How to make the field **one_or_two** readonly ?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for me. I am extending forms.Form unlike  ModelForm as in the pointed question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use disabled attribute.

```
one_or_two = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}), initial='1')
```

Comment: The form value will never be sent, and if it's mandatory then this wont work.