# How to fix this error in Django - Undefined variable:etree

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm a noobs:) I am trying to use one of the answer from @Rune in this post [In a django form, How to make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b) but I have an error as stated in the title.

Can anyone help me with this. I did try to use

> from lxml import etree - get error unresolved import:etree

and this

> from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree - get error undefined variable from import:formstring

coding

```
class ReadOnlyWidget(forms.Select):

def __init__(self, initial_widget, *args, **kwargs):
    self.initial_widget = initial_widget
    super(ReadOnlyWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def render(self, *args, **kwargs):
    def guess_readonly_text(original_content):
        root = etree.formstring("<span>%s</span>" % original_content)

        for element in root:
            if element.tag == 'input':
                return element.get('value')

            if element.tag == 'select':
                for option in element:
                    if option.get('selected'):
                        return option.text

            if element.tag == 'textarea':
                return element.text

        return "N/A"

    original_content = self.initial_widget.render(*args, **kwargs)
    try:
        readonly_text = self.initial_widget.render_readonly(*args, **kwargs)
    except AttributeError:
        readonly_text = guess_readonly_text(original_content)

    return mark_safe("""<span class="hidden">%s</span>%s""" %(original_content, readonly_text))
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `fromstring`, not `formstring`.

Comment: oppsss....sorry didn't realize that....thank you very much @Daniel......i fixed it