# displaying a 'completed' form in django

Tags: python, django, webforms

I would like to show a completed form using a model instance and the form class that was used to render the form. Basically, I want to show the 'completed' form, read-only. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b/331550#331550

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Just set the `readonly` property on your inputs for the "completed" form: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Comment: Note that as this feature is strictly client-only funny things may happen if the user removes the attribute and posts the form.

Comment: True. There are a couple of ways to do this. If it's client-side only, with readonly, there's really no reason to present the fields within a form tag to begin with, or allow the form to be posted anywhere. I'm not sure why the OP would want to present the form again, in readonly fashion. I would just present the values previously entered.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The thing is I am dealing with a huge form. It looks like having to write html just to display the values is a waste. The other thing is that some forms are familiar to everyone in a particular format. Think of paper-based forms. I thought it would make sense to use the same format.

Comment: Sure, I understand. In this case, I would make all of the fieldsets an include. This way you can render the fields in a form tag for the editable form, and without a form tag for read-only. That way you don't have a way to post the form for read-only, even if someone uses Firebug, etc, to manipulate the form.