# Can't disable select in ModelForm

Tags: django, django-admin

In my ModelForm I need to disable ForeignKey field. I tried [this thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1424453) but the select is still enabled and as I can see in html code attribute wasn't added to widget. Here's my code ModelForm code:

```
class ZayvkiAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Zayvki
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs.get('instance', None):
            if not kwargs.get('initial', None):
                kwargs['initial'] = {}
            if not kwargs['initial'].get('nomer_zayvki', None):
                kwargs['initial']['nomer_zayvki'] = get_request_number()
        super(ZayvkiAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.id:
            self.fields['tipe_zayvki'].required = False
            self.fields['tipe_zayvki'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'disabled'
            self.fields['nomer_zayvki'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

UPDATE:
I can't use `exclude` or `readonly` attrs of `ModelAdmin` because I need user to be able to add something when he creates the object. But when the object is created, I wan't user just to see the value and not to edit it.

Comment: Can you post the whole code for your ModelForm?

Comment: Hm, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Are you using `./manage.py runserver` to run your server? If so, try adding the line `print instance` just after `instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)`. When you open the edit page, you should see some output in the console running the server, somewhere between the other debug statements. Can you tell me what you see?

Comment: In instance variable there is my model object of course. When i'm debugging script I can see attribute 'disabled' attached to widget so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code in your admins.py? I've got no problems adding a dynamically disabled field in my own app. Also, what Django version are you using?

Comment: 1.5.1. I can disable text input too but it doesn't work for select. You mean post code from ModelAdmin class?

Answer (score 0):

A `MoedlAdmin` can be the solution:

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('tipe_zayvki',)
```

also there is a method named `get_readonly_fields` here an example:

```
class CustomAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['tipe_zayvki']
        else:
            return []
```

Comment: The form behavior should be more complex. I've updated the question. Please take a glimpse at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `exclude` as mentioned in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form). This will remove the field from being rendered in the form, which is a cleaner UX than a disabled form input field.

So for your example:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('tipe_zayvki', )
```

Comment: That's not an option because though user couldn't edit the value he definitely needs to see it.