# How do I set a field's read-only attribute?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to set a readonly attribute to this specific field in django. What I hope to accomplish is the field's data shows but it cant be changed. How do I go about this? Below is what I've tried and isn't working for me.

```
class editcartform(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
     model = signedup
     exclude = ['sessionid', 'price', 'paid', 'orderid', 'dancer_1_level', 'dancer_2_level', 'dancer_2_sex', 'dancer_1_sex']
     widgets = { 
        'comp_name':Textarea(attrs={'readonly'}),
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a django form, How to make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b

Comment: Ive already tried, that, It's still editable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'comp_name':Textarea(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}),
```

or

```
'comp_name':Textarea(attrs={'disabled':'disabled'}),
```

It may change depends on what you want.

Comment: When I add that I get a number (it is a foreign field) do you know how i can force it to show the item it points to in readable terms instead of just a number?