# Django: How can I render a ModelForm partially editable fields and show other fields as label items?

Tags: python, django, forms

I am doing my first app on django.

I have the following class:

```
class SolicitanteForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitante
        fields = ['congregacionOfertante', 'id_oferta', 'observaciones', 'descartado']
```

`Solicitante` extends the django `Model` class, and have other fields.

I want to use the django forms approach to render the form. But it renders only the fields defined on `Meta.fields`. I want it render the other fields but using `<label>` or `<span>` instead  of `<input>` with `readonly` attribute.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For show all fields try use `__all__` in Meta:

```
class SolicitanteForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Solicitante
        fields = '__all__'
```

For displaying the form fields is responsible [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). So you need write own widget with necessary behavior.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b), author solved a similar problem, maybe it will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readonly` HTML attribute. It will make the input tabbable but not usable. In HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="congregacionOfertante" value="Cameroon" readonly>
```

You can custom you form as following for add the HTML attribute:

```
class SolicitanteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Solicitante
        fields = ['congregacionOfertante', 'id_oferta', 'observaciones', 'descartado']
        widgets = {
            'congregacionOfertante': forms.TextInput({'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```

Ref: [HTML readonly Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

If you don't want it clickable/selectable use `disabled` attribute.

Comment: How can I prevent [this exploit](https://github.com/blog/1068-public-key-security-vulnerability-and-mitigation) mentioned [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) using the suggest you made?

Comment: Use the first approach to avoid the exploit.