# How to set a ModelForm field not editable based on other object?

Tags: django

I have Application (in the sense of applying for something) for Project which is covered by ApplicationForm which extends ModelForm. Application has a required `budget`, which makes it a required field in ApplicationForm.

If the project has a preset budget, applications against it cannot have their budgets editable on create nor on update. I found this answer on how to set a field as read-only and how to scrub that field, https://stackoverflow.com/a/325038/604511

So how do I create ApplicationForm objects that behave this way based on parent Project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to change from the mentioned answer is to edit the `if` condition:

```
class ApplicationForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.project and instance.project.budget:
            self.fields['budget'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    def clean_budget(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.project and instance.project.budget:
            return instance.budget
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['budget']
```

You can pass `project` to the form constructor via `instance` argument:

```
application = Application(project=project)
form = ApplicationForm(instance=application)
```

Comment: but a **new** ApplicationForm must change its behavior for project. I must pass the project earlier. Trying to do it by _init__'s kwargs gives me errors about unexcpected kwargs.

Comment: It would have been a disappointing work day without your answer!