# How to use "Readonly Field" outside Admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a form that I need to show my project outside the area of administration, some fields can not be edited but can see them.

To do this would be great "**AdminReadonlyField**" found in *"django.contrib.admin.helpers"* The problem is that you can not do.

[image]

I have tried to create some widget that can replace this complex class, but I can not get it to work properly with DateTiemField fields.

```
class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    We need field "date_joined" can not be edited but can see them
    """
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',
                 'email', 'date_joined', 'slug')

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['instance'] = user
        super(UserUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_joined'].widget = widgets.CMDateTimeText()

    def clean_date_joined(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.date_joined
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['date_joined']
```

My code, something is not right.

```
class CMDateTimeText(DateTimeBaseInput):
    """
    A SplitDateTime Widget that has some admin-specific styling.
    Hereda Field and Widget.
    """
    format_key = 'DATETIME_FORMAT'
    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        # Use slightly better defaults than HTML's 20x2 box
        default_attrs = {'class': 'date_id'}
        if attrs:
            default_attrs.update(attrs)
        super(CMDateTimeText, self).__init__(attrs=default_attrs, format=format)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            value = ''
        value = self._format_value(value)
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        return format_html('<p{}>{}</p>', flatatt(final_attrs), conditional_escape(value))
```

Result image:
[image]

any idea how to do "AdminReadonlyField"" any view or form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In a django form, How to make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b)

Comment: Please @rnevius verify my question not is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

So after hours of looking for various solutions, I found out how to do it the Django way.

Simply add the attribute `disabled` to the field in the form (not the widget!):

```
# in __init__() with crispy-forms for instance
self.fields['field'].disabled = True 

# as form field
field = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
```

And it works... Django is taking care of not saving the field, if some hacker tampered with it although it's disabled. Only works with Django 1.9+.

Comment: Still makes DB requests when it's a ModelChoiceField though :|

Comment: Then change it to some other field type or cache it or use a custom widget that renders only text. Django has so many ways to overcome that issue, which wasn't part of this issue though.