# Object 'Item' has no attribute 'ro_field'

Tags: python

I have edited a bit of code from here [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-to-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot-b)

```
def clean_sku(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.sku
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['sku']
```

Instead of running the code on the sku attribute of instance. I'd like to loop over multiple attributes

```
readonly = ['name', 'description', 'deadline']

def clean(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        for ro_field in self.readonly:
            if instance and instance.pk:
                return instance.ro_field
            else:
                return self.cleaned_data[ro_field]
```

which gives me the error in the title. How can I get the interpreter to interpret `instance.name`, `instance.description` and `instance.deadline` rather than `instance.ro_field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
return instance.ro_field
```

to

```
return getattr(instance, ro_field)
```

[Documentation for `getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr)