# Read-Only Field in Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, readonly

How do I set a field to read-only in a Django form? I know how to disable a field but that's not what I'm looking for. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it model-form? can you tell more of what you need

Comment: Yes, it is a CharField of a ModelForm.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the optional `attrs` parameter when defining the `Field`.  To wit:

```
somefield = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'})
)
```

Answer (score 20):

In **django 1.9** in a Field.disabled attribute available : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

*The disabled boolean argument, when set to True, disables a form field using the disabled HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.*

**otherwise**

use the widget 'readonly' attribute

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(PatientForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['field'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
```

Comment: The Django documentation is patently false here; in the case of using the disabled attribute, the value is not ignored in favor of the form's initial data; the value is not passed at all.

Comment: The `form` data is not saved in the `database` when fields are `disabled`.

Answer (score 15):

In `Django 1.9+`:

```
somefield = forms.CharField(disabled=True)
```

Comment: Important thing to note is the fields will not submit to the server when they are `disabled`. If you want the field data to be posted make it `readonly`

Comment: there is no attribute called "readonly", please propose a solution if you have. --Thanks

Comment: Yes `readonly` is not a core field argument. So use the other answers. eg. `field.widget.attrs['readonly'] = True`

Comment: @stephen I think your last answer should be added to the response because it is the one that saved my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of the best way to do it in front side is [widget-tweak](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) even more if you use your form in multiple view.

If you don't want to install extra lib you can simply add field manually and use the django input attribut.
Like this :

```html
<input 
    name="{{ form.fieldname.name }}" 
    type="{{ form.fieldname.widget.input_type }}" 
    readonly="readonly"
    >
</input>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the only way I get it to work in Js:

```
function myFieldOnChange() {
    var myField= document.getElementById("myFieldID")
    myField.setAttribute('readonly', true)
```

Comment: there is 1000 way to set in front... Create HTML input with same name as back input form and submiting the from will also work. `<input id="myFieldID" name="backEndFieldName" readonly>` will work

Comment: @CallMarl, I showed how you can do this dinamically based on any field OnChange event. Notice that this is different than disabling the field, as mentioned on another comment.
The way you showed only applies if you want the field to always be readonly. My solution is when you need it to be readonly on demand. Feel free to share the other 999 ways.