# Read-only field with pre-populated data in django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have following snippets,

```
# models.py
class Test(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()


# forms.py
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields = ('username', 'email')


# views.py
def test(request):
    email = "example@example.com"
    """
    How to pass and show the 'email' in django form/template?
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    return render(request, 'test.html', {"form": form})
```

---

How can I ***show and re-use*** the value of `email` variable (ie,`example@example.com`) in  Django form/template as a ***`read-only field`***?

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot

Comment: Also very related, almost a dupe of the former question i commented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271979/read-only-field-in-django-form/41272908

Comment: @BrianH. `disabled=True` doing the job ***partially***. It's not showing the value of `email` field

Comment: yeah, that's why i said it's not an exact duplicate.

Comment: @BrianH. Anyway I got the answer after little digging :)

Answer (score 0):

try to do this way:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    .....
    email = forms.EmailField(initial='{{ context.email }}', disabled=True)
    .....
```

context, passed from view, should have 'email'