# Preserving disabled form field value in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm running into an issue where my form is not preserving the form field value on a failed form submission. The catch is that I want it to be visible to the user that they can't select any other state (since it's a website specifically for a city within the state), so I have it disabled. If I remove this widget attribute, it preserves the field info, otherwise, it resets and I can't edit the field since I have it disabled. Request a remedy or a recommendation. Code follows.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Resource
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateSelect
from localflavor.us.forms import USZipCodeField
import pickle

zips = pickle.load(open('../zips.p', "rb"))


def validate_zip(zip_code):
    """Ensure zip provided by user is in King County."""
    if zip_code not in zips:
        raise ValidationError(
            '{} is not a valid King County zip code.'.format(zip_code),
            params={'zip_code': zip_code},
        )


class ResourceForm(ModelForm):
    """Form for editing and creating resources."""

    zip_code = forms.IntegerField(validators=[validate_zip])

    class Meta:
        model = Resource
        fields = ['main_category', 'org_name',
                  'description', 'street', 'city', 'state', 'zip_code', 'website',
              'phone_number', 'image', 'tags']
        labels = {
            'org_name': 'Name of Organization',
            'main_category': 'Main Categories',
        }
        help_texts = {
            'main_category': 'The core services your organization provides.',
        }
        widgets = {
            'state': USStateSelect(attrs={'disabled': True}),
        }
```

models.py (fields)

```
org_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
description = models.TextField(max_length=512)
street = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='Seattle')
state = USStateField(default='WA')
zip_code = USZipCodeField(null=True, blank=True)
website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = PhoneNumberField()
tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos', null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py (for this view alone)

```
class CreateResource(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    """Class-based view to create new resources."""

    template_name = 'searchlist/resource_form.html'
    form_class = ResourceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: Sorry about that, just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers ignore inputs that have the `disabled` attribute set.  Set `readonly` on the input instead; the input will not be editable but its value will be included when the form is submitted.

```
    widgets = {
        'state': USStateSelect(attrs={'readonly': True}),
    }
```

Comment: It's worth looking at the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/324477/5320906 also.