# In Django, how do I add the contents of two fields and display the results in a third field?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to learn Django and am finding it frustratingly difficult to do fairly basic things. I have the following form classes:

```
from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
  field1 = forms.FloatField(label="First field: ")
  field2 = forms.FloatField(label="Second field: ")

class OutputForm(forms.Form):
  outfield = forms.FloatField(label="Result: ")
```

And the following template:

```
<form>
    {{ input_form.as_ul }}
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" name="submit_button">
</form>

<form>
    {{ output_form.as_ul }}
</form>
```

And finally, the following view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import InputForm, OutputForm

def index(request):

    if request.GET.get('submit_button'):
        # ?????

    else:
        input_form = InputForm()
        output_form = OutputForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'input_form': input_form, 
                                            'output_form': output_form})
```

All I want to happen is that when I hit the submit button, the values in first field and second field get added and displayed in the result field. I know from debug outputs that the ????? commented block is run when I press the button, but I have so far not been able to figure out what to do to actually access or alter the data in my fields. I don't care about keeping a record of these transactions so it feels like storing these in a database is tremendous overkill. What is the correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things at work here, lets go through them one by one.

**1. Calculating the output value**

Use the request data to build the form, validate it, and then calculate the sum:

```
if request.GET.get('submit_button'):
    input_form = InputForm(request.GET)
    if input_form.is_valid():
       data = input_form.cleaned_data
       result = data["field1"] + data["field2"]
```

**2. Read-only output**

It's not clear why you're using a submittable form field for data that is to be calculated by your app, as opposed to playing the result into a regular html 'label' in the template. If you really want/need to set the result in a form field, I'd at least make it read-only. See [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot) for an example of how to do that.

**3. Set the output data in the form**

Set the output form/field's `initial` data to the result you have calculated. following on form the code at (1):

```
       result = data["field1"] + data["field2"]
       output_form = OutputForm(initial={"outfield": result})
```

then render the view as you're already doing:

```
       return render(
           request,
           'index.html',
           {'input_form': input_form, 'output_form': output_form},
       )
```

Comment: I originally had that field as readonly but took it out because I wanted to cut this code down to the very basics. Beyond that, for some reason I'm unable to get into the `if input_form.is_valid():` block. What would cause these fields to evaluate as invalid?

Comment: take a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors.as_data e.g. `input_form.errors.as_data()`. That said, if you render your form (even when it has errors) then the errors should be nicely rendered too.

Comment: Oh I noticed your manually-rendered form is broken - it looks like your submission button is part of a differnet form. You'll need the submit button to be part of the same form you have the `{{ input_form.as_ul }}` in.

Comment: I didn't realize it was rendering the errors because it was just that the fields were required. Which... is super confusing, because that shouldn't be a problem when I filled the forms, right? I have some more research to do.

Comment: Ah, so the button can't be separate. I find that counterintuitive, but if that's what the framework needs then I will adjust my expectations. Thanks for your assistance, this is working now. I'll edit my original template to be correct for future reference. If someone else encounters a similar problem it'd be better that they not get confused by my button placement I think.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a form to display the result. When the form is valid, you can get the values from the form's `cleaned_data` and calculate `result`.

```
def index(request):
    result = None  # Set to None by default

    if request.GET.get('submit_button'):  # The submit button was pressed
        input_form = InputForm(request.GET)  # Bind the form to the GET data
        if input_form.is_valid():
            result = input_form.cleaned_data['field1'] + input_form.cleaned_data['field2']  # Calculate the result
    else:
        input_form = InputForm()  # Submit button was not pressed - create an unbound (blank) form
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'input_form': input_form, result:result})
```

Then in your template, include `{{ result }}` instead of the output form.

Comment: Doesn't this fail to return anything when the button is pressed? Or did you mean for the last line with the return to be outside the if/else? Altering a bit to get a return in both cases, I get the same invalid field problem I mentioned commenting on @Tom Dalton's answer.

Comment: The last line was indented incorrectly. It sounds like you might have got the ‘invalid field’ error because the submit button was integrated wrong framework. Note that’s not a limitation of Django, it’s the way html works.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the initial poperty on a field prefills it:

```
output_form.fields['outfield'].initial = input_form.data.get ('field1') + input_form.data.get ('field1')
```

You need to pass request.POST or request.GET into OutputForm when you instantiate it. You should also be calling is_valid() on the from and using cleaned_data instead of data after you check if it is valid.