# Django Disable/Exclude Field in CreateView but enable/include it in UpdateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I would like to exclude/disable a Charfield (with options and a default value) when creating a new object, but when editing this object, I would like to enable / include the Charfield for the user to change it.

So far I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot) I found here on Stackoverflow, but it wasn't the full solution for me. The Charfield did get disabled but when I tried to create my object, Django would always tell me that the field is required (even though it has a Default Value).

My code:

```
class OfferCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Offer
        exclude = ['date', 'number']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        super(OfferCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = False
        else:
            self.fields['status'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.help_text_inline = True
        self.helper.add_layout(Layout(
            Fieldset('Angebot',
                     Row(
                         Div(
                             Field('name'),
                             css_class='col-sm-12'
                         ),
                         Div(
                             Field('category'),
                             css_class='col-sm-6'
                         ),
                         Div(
                             Field('status'),
                             css_class='col-sm-6'
                         ),
                     )),
            Fieldset('Kunde',
                    Row(
                        Div(
                            Field('customer', css_class='selectize'),
                            css_class='col-sm-6'
                        ),
                        Div(
                            Field('receiver', css_class='selectize'),
                            css_class='col-sm-6'
                        ),
                    )),
            Fieldset('Kundeninformation',
                    Row(
                        Div(
                            Field('introduction'),
                            css_class='col-sm-12'
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            Fieldset('Zusätzliche Informationen',
                    Row(
                        Div(
                            Field('footer'),
                            css_class='col-sm-12',
                        ),

                    ),
                ),
            ))

    def clean_status(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.status
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['status']
```

The status field in my model:

```
status = models.CharField(default="CREATED", max_length=255, choices=STATUSES, verbose_name="Status")
```

Also note: the clean_status function is never called. I tried to debug in it, but apparently this function does absolutely nothing.

I know I could create two different forms, but I would like to avoid that if possible, also please no Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can completely remove field from fields list instead of disable it using `fields.pop()` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
    super(OfferCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    if instance and instance.pk:
        self.fields.pop('status')
```

As for the div part you can do something like this:

```
divs = [Div(
    Field('name'),
    css_class='col-sm-12'
),
    Div(
        Field('category'),
        css_class='col-sm-6'
    )]

if not instance and not instance.pk:
    divs.append(Div(
        Field('status'),
        css_class='col-sm-6'
    ))

self.helper.add_layout(Layout(
    Fieldset('Angebot',
            Row(*divs)))
```

Comment: I tried that once, but sadly I always get the error `Could not resolve form field 'status'.`

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski can you post full traceback?

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski not sure but looks like the problem is here `Div(
                             Field('status'),
                             css_class='col-sm-6'
                         ),`. You need to remove it also if instance is not None.

Comment: you mean remove the whole `Div(Field('status'), css_class='col-sm-6'),` ?

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski yes, but only `if instance and instance.pk` is True.

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski I added example how you can do it. Check update.