# django disabled Booleanfield not submitted on POST method

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a BooleanField that given certain conditions, needs to be disabled.

How can I submitting the input even if it's disabled

[first time form submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W2dO.png)
[second time form submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ7Xj.png) that ignore disabled booleanfield

**views.py**

```
def test(request):
    form = InformationForm()
    test_table = TestTable.objects.get(id=1)
    result = ''

    if test_table.status == True:
        result = True
        form.fields['agree'].initial = True    
        form.fields['agree'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
        # form.fields['agree'].widget.attrs={'onclick': 'return false','style':'opacity: 0.4 !important'}

    if request.method == "POST":
        post_form = InformationForm(request.POST)
        result = post_form['agree'].value()
        text = post_form['text'].value()

        if post_form['agree'].value() == True:
            t = TestTable.objects.filter(id=1).first()
            t.status = 1
            t.save()

            post_form.fields['agree'].initial = True  
            post_form.fields['agree'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True
           #post_form.fields['agree'].widget.attrs={'onclick': 'return false','style':'opacity: 0.4 !important'}
            return render(request,'test.html',context={'form':post_form,'result':result,'text':text})

    text = form['text'].value()
    return render(request,'test.html',context={'form':form,'result':result})
```

every time disabled BooleanField returns false, even it selected 
[i am also referred this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot)

**forms.py**

```
class InformationForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    agree = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    def clean(self):
        agree = self.cleaned_data.get('agree')
        text = self.cleaned_data.get('text')

    #def clean_agree(self):
    #    if self.instance and self.instance.pk:
    #        return self.instance.agree
    #    else:
    #        return self.cleaned_data.get('agree')
```

Comment: you should set disabled on the field, not on the widget (`post_form.fields['agree'].disabled = True`) and you should not use the `value()` of a field but the actual `cleaned_data`: `if form.is_valid(): result = form.cleaned_data['agree']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an intentional design decision by Django so that users can't edit the HTML input and remove the `disabled` attribute, which could enable users to update values they aren't meant to update. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#disabled):

> The `disabled` boolean argument, when set to `True`, disables a form field using the `disabled` HTML attribute so that it won’t be editable by users. Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.

I recommend updating your form class's `__init__()` method so that it only adds the `disabled` attribute when the field is meant to be disabled.