# How to use Field.disabled in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, forms, django-models

I would like to have the slug input field be set to read only but can't seem to utilize "Field.disabled" properly. How can I do that in a simple Django form?

This is my model

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    body = models.TextField()
    thumb = models.ImageField(default='default.png', blank=True)
```

This is my forms.py

```
class CreateArticle(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'slug', 'thumb']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot)

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot (and it also sounds like field.disabled may not be exactly what you want if you want it to be readonly)

Comment: No, it doesn't. It is a chain of answers that leads back to the Django documentation. Was hoping for an answer that was adapted to my specific situation.

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable your `slug` field the `__init__` method:

```
class CreateArticle(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = ['title', 'body', 'slug', 'thumb']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["slug"].disabled = True
        # Or to set READONLY
        self.fields["slug"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True
```