# Access Django ModelChoiceField form field value inside __init__

Tags: django

I would like to make the certain field in my formset read-only once the value has been chosen. Kind of like this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.fields["my_field"].value is not None:
            self.fields["my_field"].disabled == True
```

Except ModelChoiceField object doesn't have an argument `value` and I am not even sure `__init__` it is the right place to try access value of a formset form's field.

**UPDATE**

```
if self["my_field"].value() is not None:
    self.fields["my_field"].disabled = True
```

does the trick. But reveals another issue. When I change the other field's value in this form and try and save it, I get `This field is required.` error on the disabled field. Does `disabled` argument have any effect on the fields value in `form.is_valid`? Because according to man `Even if a user tampers with the field’s value submitted to the server, it will be ignored in favor of the value from the form’s initial data.` And initial data is actually `None`. I guess I need to find another way to make the field read-only (like simply ignore the change in the `post`).

Comment: You can use `self.fields[field_name].initial` or `self["field_name"].value()` or `self.instance`.

Comment: ```self["field_name"].value()``` works, thanks. ```self.fields[field_name].initial``` returns ```None``` for all fields at this case.

Comment: You can use instead an attribute `readonly`. A form will still submit an input field that is `readonly`, but will not submit an input field that is `disabled`!. You can also add it in `__init__` method, [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66108267/6143954)