# Making a django model field readonly

Tags: python, django

I am creating a django DB model and I want one the fields to be readonly. When creating a new object I want to set it, but later if someone tries to update the object, it should raise an error. How do I achieve that?

I tried the following but I was still able to update the objects.

```
from django.db import models as django_db_models


class BalanceHoldAmounts(django_db_models.Model):
    read_only_field = django_db_models.DecimalField(editable=False)
```

Thank you

Comment: you can do it in forms.py file

Comment: you can find multiple solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot

Comment: I am not using django to create forms. I use it only as a DB ORM for my backend.

Comment: then this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can override it in the "save" method of the model and raise a Validation Error if someone tries to update that field.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk:
        previous_value = BalanceHoldAmounts.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if previous_value.read_only_field != self.read_only_field:
            raise ValidationError("The read_only_field can not be changed")    
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Warning! This won't save if the object doesn't have an id! That only makes it readonly once the object is created!

Comment: Indentation was mistaken in earlier code. I have corrected it. Other are fine