# Automatic field filling based on user information

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I want the name field to be filled automatically based on the user's information and the user cannot change it while filling the form.
But nothing can be written in the field, nor is it automatically filled, and the form is not sent.
It should be noted that without this option, the form works perfectly.

models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    choice = (
        ('d', 'Dark'),
        ('s', 'Sweet'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    seller_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    desc = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=choice)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="img/", null=True)      
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=228, default = None, blank = True, null = 
               True)
    active_bool=models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

forms:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.CharField(disabled=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['title', 'category', 'seller_price', 'desc', 'status', 'image', 
                'image_url']

        def __init__(self, args, kwargs):
            super(ProductForm, self).__init__(args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['user'].initial = kwargs['initial']['user']



or


class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            self.fields['user'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

    def clean_user(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.user
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data['user']
        
    model = Product
    fields = ['user', 'title', 'category', 'seller_price', 'desc', 'status', 'image', 'image_url']
```

views:

```
def create_product(request):
    form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            form = ProductForm()
    return render(request, 'auctions/create_product.html', {'form': form})
```

html:

```
{% block body %}
<h2>Create New Product</h2>

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% else %}
    Not signed in.
{% endif %}
```

{% endblock %}

Answer (score 1):

Django 1.9 and onwards have a 'disabled' attribute to form fields: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.Field.disabled

if you make the field have a default value and be disabled it should solve your problem

if you need more clarification consider checking this trend too: [In a Django form, how do I make a field readonly (or disabled) so that it cannot be edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot)

it seems to be the same problem you are having

Comment: Thanks, but if I use this line of code and write it before `Meta`, it still has the same result.`user = forms.CharField(disabled=True)`

Comment: I have shown the changes in the question. Please check again.

Comment: I strongly recommend you check the response to this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324477/in-a-django-form-how-do-i-make-a-field-readonly-or-disabled-so-that-it-cannot. 

The response there should fix your problem

Comment: With these changes, the form works as per the given template, but the user can choose their own name.
It means, in fact, what I want to do is not done....I have shown the changes in the question. Please check again.

Comment: And let me also say that the form has not been completed yet. The information is received only for the use of the user's username and cannot be changed.

Comment: Can you send the code according to my codes?
No matter how hard I tried. it did not work.